# Jackson serialiser on Spring boot is stringifying my Strings

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I'm sending a JSON to my API as following :

`"{}"` and I want that it will be interpreted as JSON and not string. Because the API is adding a double quote to my String and the payload becomes

```
""{}""
```

I used @Consumes(MediaType.JSON_APPLICATION) and it doesn't work...

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete")
public String delete(@RequestBody String json) {

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json); //This line throws exception 

}
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the @Consumes(MediaType.JSON_APPLICATION) is a JAX-RS annotation that not considered while using SPring MVC annotation.

To resolve this issue I shouldn't use

```
@Consumes(MediaType.JSON_APPLICATION)
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete")
```

but I should use:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete", consumes = MediaType.JSON_APPLICATION)
```

This resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

because you declare the body as String by `@RequestBody String json`

what you want is

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;


public ResponseEntity delete(@RequestBody JsonNode json) {

 if (!VeryCustomService.isValid(json)) {
     throw new ResponseStatusException(BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid json: " + json);

 return new ResponseEntity("Success", OK);
  }
}
```

I would also recommend to use `ResponseEntity` for the response type rather than `String`, and throw ResponseStatusException if the input is not valid.

Comment: Yes Thanks, Using JsonNode instead of String is a better solution and it resolve my issue ... thanks